# Haproxy frontend configuration to replace response header depending on query string

Tags: configuration, load-balancing, haproxy

I used the following haproxy configuration in frontend to modify the response header of requests depending on a query string:

```
frontend my-frontend
   acl is-foo urlp(foo) 1
   http-response replace-header Set-Cookie "(.*)" "\1; SameSite=None" if is-foo
```

Depending on my information from the docs the acl should match for all requests like

```
example.com?a=b&foo=1&bar=2
example.com?foo=1
example.com?a=b&foo=1
```

And it should not match for requests like

```
example.com?a=b&foo=0&bar=2
example.com?a=b
example.com?a=b&foo=bar
```

The actual result is that the acl matches never.
If i invert the `if` i.e.: `if !is-foo` the replace-header happens on every request.
So the problem must be the acl which matches never.

I use haproxy 2.0.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by myself.

It seems to be the case that `urlp(foo)` is not present at runtime when it has been executed for http-response.

So we need to store its value in a temporary variable using `set-var(custom.name)`, before. At runtime in if condition we can access it with `var(custom.name)` and match it against our condition. I used `urlp_val()` instead of `urlp()` here because the value will be casted to int immediately.

```
frontend my-frontend
    http-request set-var(txn.foo) urlp_val(foo)
    http-response replace-header Set-Cookie "(.*)" "\1; SameSite=None" if { var(txn.foo) eq 1 }
```

Thank you for traveling.